# BlogEngine Razor Pages Not Rendering

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, razor

I'm using Web site project version 2.7 with VS2010 with IIS7.5 on both my workstation and server, and neither the Dashboard or Appearance .cshtml razor pages were rendering - I was getting a 404.

I added .cshtml as an extension under Mime Types, with a MIME type of text/html, and installed MVC4. This fixed it on my local but I cannot get this to work on the server (**Windows 2008 R2**).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:

http://www.adamwlewis.com/articles/iis-7-not-serving-files-4047-error